# Node + xmldom: How do I change the value of a single XML field in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, domparser

Using [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) v.0.10.29, [Express](http://expressjs.com/) v4.12.0, and [xmldom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom) v0.1.19, I'm trying to do the following:

## Steps

1. Read an **XML file into a string**
2. **Convert the string** into an **XML object** using [xmldom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom)
3. Set the `<name>default</name>` field to `<name>test</name>`
4. **Convert the XML object back into a string**

## Problem

*The problem is that after I set the `<name>` field, it sets correctly in the object, but when I convert it to a string, the `<name>` field is back to being the old value (wrong).*

## Code

Here's what the code looks like for this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
var XMLSerializer = require('xmldom').XMLSerializer;
var filename = "myFile.xml";

fs.readFile(filename, "utf-8", function (err,data) 
{
    //CREATE/PARSE XML OBJECT FROM STRING
    var customerConfig = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data);

    //SET VALUE TO "TEST" (<name>default</name> TO <name>test</name>)
    customerConfig.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = "test";

    //THIS OUTPUTS "test" WHICH IS CORRECT - 
    console.log(customerConfig.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

    //SERIALIZE TO STRING
    var xmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(customerConfig);

    //THIS OUTPUTS THE FULL XML FILE, 
    //BUT STILL SHOWS <name>default</name> AND NOT <name>test</name>
    console.log(xmlString);
});
```

**The problem is that the `<name>` field isn't setting to `test`** in the string... I'm thinking there is a **problem with the serialization part?** Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well I figured out the problem!

I was setting **`nodeValue`** but I really needed to set **`data`**. So I changed

```
customerConfig.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = "test";
```

to

```
customerConfig.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].data= "test";
```

then it worked!

Comment: Thanks so much for this Q&A.  It saves me countless time.  Just for my own record. 1. the new value to be set must be a string; 2.`firstChild` can be used instead of `childNodes[0]`